# Set Visual Studio font size for "Error List" tool window only?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, ide

In **Visual Studio 2017**, is it possible to change the UI font size for the IDE **Error List** tool window *only*, i.e., without affecting any other settings?

Having said this, I can't even find *any* setting in *Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors* that affects the **Error List** at all, even after restarting Visual Studio as suggested.

Answer (score 10):

It is done by changing the Environment Font. It changes the menu font too.

> Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors->Environment

Comment: Ok, but the OP (me) did ask if it was possible without affecting anything else, especially not so much as the entire vs2017 menu font...

Comment: Thanks! it's also useful in ATMEL Studio 7.0 !

Comment: Does anyone know what the "automatic" font style is by default? Mine is set to "automatic", which means that the setting for the size is greyed out. I want to change the size, not the typeface. Also, it would be nice for this to be more easily changed (Ctrl + scroll would be ideal) for people who switch between vastly different screen sizes often.

Comment: @RoG I think it's supposed to be "Segoe UI" ... but I'm also having trouble with this at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and couldn't resolve in Visual Studio (the font size updates in other areas of VS, but the error list stays the same).

I only needed a bigger font for a presentation so used the **magnifier tool** in Windows.  Not something you want to use all the time, but great for a short-term need

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio (2022 and most likely older) does not allow to change the font of the error list independently from the rest of the environment.

Somebody asked for the default font of the environment. The default font is "Segoe UI" with font size 9.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).